Is it normal to get pywinauto.uia_defines.NoPatternInterfaceError
I wrote a program to automate the test of an app i did not create using pywinauto, but i got this error : pywinauto.uia_defines.NoPatternInterfaceError. It came when i tried this :
    app.connect(path=exe_path)
    main_dlg = app.top_window()
    main_dlg.wait('visible')
    truc = main_dlg.child_window(title="Users", control_type="Button")
    truc.click() # <- this is where the problem arised

Here is the code (so that you understand the context) :
from pywinauto.application import Application

*
* This is irrevelent
*

try:
    print("start")
    app = Application(backend="uia").start(exe_path)

    app.connect(path=exe_path)
    main_dlg = app.top_window()
    print("Is there a window : "+ str(main_dlg.exists()))
    main_dlg.wait('visible')


    # Here we can start to work

    # This let us see what the API see in the selected window
    main_dlg.print_control_identifiers()
    print(str(main_dlg.actions))

    truc = main_dlg.child_window(title="Users", control_type="Button")
    print(type(truc))
    print(str(truc))
    truc.print_control_identifiers()
    truc.click()

except Exception as e:
    print("PROBLEM")
    print("--------------------------------------------------------------")
    raise(e)
finally:
    print("Finally")

And here is what it print :
C:\Users\vboxuser\Documents\GST_tests\automation.py:3: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\P'
  exe_path = "xxx"
start
Is there a window : True
Control Identifiers:

Dialog - 'xxx'    (L-8, T-8, R1928, B868)
['xxxDialog', 'Dialog', 'xxx']
child_window(title="xxx", control_type="Window")
   |
   | TitleBar - ''    (L16, T-5, R1920, B23)
   | ['TitleBar']
   |    |
   |    | Menu - 'Système'    (L0, T0, R22, B22)
   |    | ['SystèmeMenu', 'Système', 'Menu', 'Système0', 'Système1']
   |    | child_window(title="Système", auto_id="MenuBar", control_type="MenuBar")
   |    |    |
   |    |    | MenuItem - 'Système'    (L0, T0, R22, B22)
   |    |    | ['Système2', 'MenuItem', 'SystèmeMenuItem']
   |    |    | child_window(title="Système", control_type="MenuItem")
   |    |
   |    | Button - 'Réduire'    (L1779, T8, R1826, B22)
   |    | ['Button', 'Réduire', 'RéduireButton', 'Button0', 'Button1']
   |    | child_window(title="Réduire", control_type="Button")
   |    |
   |    | Button - 'Restaurer'    (L1826, T8, R1872, B22)
   |    | ['Button2', 'RestaurerButton', 'Restaurer']
   |    | child_window(title="Restaurer", control_type="Button")
   |    |
   |    | Button - 'Fermer'    (L1872, T8, R1928, B22)
   |    | ['Button3', 'FermerButton', 'Fermer']
   |    | child_window(title="Fermer", control_type="Button")
   |
   | Image - ''    (L16, T39, R408, B103)
   | ['Image']
   |
   | Button - 'Logon'    (L0, T120, R100, B170)
   | ['Logon', 'Button4', 'LogonButton', 'Logon0', 'Logon1']
   | child_window(title="Logon", control_type="Button")
   |    |
   |    | Static - 'Logon'    (L33, T137, R67, B152)
   |    | ['Logon2', 'Static', 'LogonStatic', 'Static0', 'Static1']
   |    | child_window(title="Logon", control_type="Text")
   |
   | Button - 'Hardware'    (L0, T170, R100, B220)
   | ['Hardware', 'Button5', 'HardwareButton', 'Hardware0', 'Hardware1']
   | child_window(title="Hardware", control_type="Button")
   |    |
   |    | Static - 'Hardware'    (L24, T187, R76, B202)
   |    | ['Hardware2', 'Static2', 'HardwareStatic']
   |    | child_window(title="Hardware", control_type="Text")
   |
   | Button - 'SNTP'    (L0, T220, R100, B270)
   | ['Button6', 'SNTP', 'SNTPButton', 'SNTP0', 'SNTP1']
   | child_window(title="SNTP", control_type="Button")
   |    |
   |    | Static - 'SNTP'    (L36, T237, R64, B252)
   |    | ['SNTPStatic', 'Static3', 'SNTP2']
   |    | child_window(title="SNTP", control_type="Text")
   |
   | Button - 'Network'    (L0, T270, R100, B320)
   | ['Button7', 'NetworkButton', 'Network', 'Network0', 'Network1']
   | child_window(title="Network", control_type="Button")
   |    |
   |    | Static - 'Network'    (L27, T287, R73, B302)
   |    | ['Static4', 'NetworkStatic', 'Network2']
   |    | child_window(title="Network", control_type="Text")
   |
   | Button - 'Users'    (L0, T320, R100, B370)
   | ['UsersButton', 'Button8', 'Users', 'Users0', 'Users1']
   | child_window(title="Users", control_type="Button")
   | *
   | *
   | *
   | * Not useful info that i cut
   | *
   | *
   | *
   | Button - 'Firmware'    (L0, T570, R100, B620)
   | ['Button13', 'Firmware', 'FirmwareButton', 'Firmware0', 'Firmware1']
   | child_window(title="Firmware", control_type="Button")
   |    |
   |    | Static - 'Firmware'    (L26, T587, R74, B602)
   |    | ['Static10', 'FirmwareStatic', 'Firmware2']
   |    | child_window(title="Firmware", control_type="Text")
<pywinauto.actionlogger._StandardLogger object at 0x000001C3EC87B290>
<class 'pywinauto.application.WindowSpecification'>
<pywinauto.application.WindowSpecification object at 0x000001C3EDAC3410>
Control Identifiers:

Button - 'Users'    (L0, T320, R100, B370)
['UsersButton', 'Button', 'Users', 'Users0', 'Users1']
child_window(title="Users", control_type="Button")
   |
   | Static - 'Users'    (L36, T337, R64, B352)
   | ['Static', 'Users2', 'UsersStatic']
   | child_window(title="Users", control_type="Text")
PROBLEM
--------------------------------------------------------------
Finally
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vboxuser\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\pywinauto\uia_defines.py", line 234, in get_elem_interface
    iface = cur_ptrn.QueryInterface(cls_name)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vboxuser\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py", line 828, in QueryInterface
    self.__com_QueryInterface(byref(iid), byref(p))
ValueError: NULL COM pointer access

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vboxuser\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\uia_controls.py", line 121, in click
    self.invoke()
  File "C:\Users\vboxuser\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\uiawrapper.py", line 513, in invoke
    self.iface_invoke.Invoke()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vboxuser\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\uiawrapper.py", line 132, in __get__
    value = self.fget(obj)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vboxuser\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\uiawrapper.py", line 231, in iface_invoke
    return uia_defs.get_elem_interface(elem, "Invoke")
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vboxuser\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\pywinauto\uia_defines.py", line 236, in get_elem_interface
    raise NoPatternInterfaceError()
pywinauto.uia_defines.NoPatternInterfaceError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vboxuser\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\pywinauto\uia_defines.py", line 234, in get_elem_interface
    iface = cur_ptrn.QueryInterface(cls_name)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vboxuser\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py", line 828, in QueryInterface
    self.__com_QueryInterface(byref(iid), byref(p))
ValueError: NULL COM pointer access

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vboxuser\Documents\GST_tests\automation.py", line 31, in <module>
    raise(e)
  File "C:\Users\vboxuser\Documents\GST_tests\automation.py", line 26, in <module>
    truc.click()
  File "C:\Users\vboxuser\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\uia_controls.py", line 123, in click
    self.select()
  File "C:\Users\vboxuser\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\uiawrapper.py", line 605, in select
    self.iface_selection_item.Select()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vboxuser\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\uiawrapper.py", line 132, in __get__
    value = self.fget(obj)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vboxuser\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\uiawrapper.py", line 224, in iface_selection_item
    return uia_defs.get_elem_interface(elem, "SelectionItem")
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vboxuser\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\pywinauto\uia_defines.py", line 236, in get_elem_interface
    raise NoPatternInterfaceError()
pywinauto.uia_defines.NoPatternInterfaceError

From what i understand and what i saw in the documentation and the exemples, Users Button should be a clickable element. Did i do something wrong ?
Also, i found this post : github issue link that seems to have a similar issue. I also tried to use win32 backend instead of uia, but i got the same result as ripdog.
In the end it can be sumurised as : Is it my fault ? Is there an alternative way to click Button elements ?

Unfortunately not every application implements click handlers and other handlers properly on the application side. So it is kind of norm. :( But methods .click_input(), .type_keys(...) and similar should always work since they use native mouse and keyboard events. They only need active desktop: it means the PC is not locked or RDP window is not minimized and not disconnected. About RDP you can read Remote Execution Guide for proper settings and other workarounds.

click_input() worked like a charm ! Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately i can only flag your answer, i can't select it as a valid answer or even up it to give you points. My gratitude will be your only reward.

No problem. Since it solves your problem, I've posted it as an answer. You should be able to mark the answer as accepted below, at the left side of the answer a gray check box should work. Upvote button will work after getting 15 points of reputation.

Unfortunately not every application implements click handlers and other handlers properly on the application side. So it is kind of norm. :( But methods .click_input(), .type_keys(...) and similar should always work since they use native mouse and keyboard events. They only need active desktop: it means the PC is not locked or RDP window is not minimized and not disconnected. About RDP you can read Remote Execution Guide for proper settings and other workarounds
